# IOS project code coverage source file is relative path

Tags: ios, xcode, code-coverage, lcov

I have generated .gcno and .gcda files after running my iphone app.Then I use cover story to view the coverage rate.However, cover story could not open the source file and I found that the source path is a relative path, not full path.All I can see is full of /*EOF*/ in the screen. 
The strange to me is that only some of the files could not open due to this path issue. Most of them are full path and cover story can open them successfully.Unable to attach screenshot

How can I show the correct path names in CoverStory?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest generating an HTML report with lcov, which allos you to normalize the directory names.

Other benefits of using an HTML report are:

- The coverage information is available on both desktop machines as well as from a Continuous Integration build server.

**To install lcov**

- Use Homebrew or MacPorts

Example:

```
brew install lcov
```

**First Generate Datafile**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e # fail script if any commands fail
${gen.info} ${temp.dir}/coverage-data/*.gcno --no-recursion --output-filename \
${temp.dir}/${module.name}-temp.info
#Remove symbols we're not interested in.
${lcov} -r ${temp.dir}/${module.name}-temp.info > ${temp.dir}/${module.name}.info
```

**Now Generate the HTML Report**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e # fail script if any commands fail

${gen.html} --no-function-coverage --no-branch-coverage -o ${coverage.reports.dir} \
--prefix ${basedir} ${temp.dir}/${module.name}.info
```

If you're interested, I have an build script the produces HTML reports [here](https://github.com/jasperblues/Typhoon/blob/master/build.xml). An example report: http://jasperblues.github.io/Typhoon/coverage/index.html

Comment: Hi,Jasper. I use lcov tool to generate html report with .gcda and .gcno files together,but I found the report missed a lot of .m files , only its .h file listed.Do I miss something?

Comment: Yes, the .m files should be in there. See the sample report that I linked to? . . when you tried CoverStory where the .m files there?

Comment: Yes,I can see the .m and .h files with coverstory. Not sure why missing some .m information in the report.